# Change Columns based on DataType DataGrid WPF

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to have different columns based on the datatype that is set on the `DataGrid`.

Example: if I supply ItemsSource of "`core.Customer`" or "`core.ServiceLocation`" I want different columns based on that datatype. How do? I constantly find conflicting information. I need guidance for this.

Edit: By the way I was hoping to define the columns via XAML, and load the "template" programmatically or define a "DataType" so it'd immediately know what column template to use.

Also, I have nested properties in my classes that i'd like to display.

Example: Customer class has "BillingName" property. I don't want to display "BillingName" I want to display "BillingName.First" and "BillingName.Last" instead. How to achieve this desired functionality?

Comment: If you simply set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `true` on your `DataGrid`, it should automatically generate columns for any public properties on your item type.  When the `ItemsSource` changes, the columns should be regenerated.  (In fact, this property is true _by default_, so in theory you should not have to do anything other than set your `ItemsSource`.)

Comment: I have alot of nested properties that don't get shown. I need to be able to define the binding specifically on each column. Example: "{binding Path=BillingName.First}" Is one of the properties I want to display.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours of searching stackoverflow and google I found [this](http://paulstovell.com/blog/dynamic-datagrid) which has my exact functionality desired under "Rendering templated columns"